# SwiftUI, create floating button and need can move anywhere like Assistive Touch

Tags: swiftui

I used to Hybrid_App WKWebview Swift 5.1 SwiftUI.
I want to create floating button can move anywhere over WKWebview.

Comment: maybe provide example code you are using is better

Comment: the code is like example below because FloatingView is Button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to my understanding of your question, you want a floating button over WKWebview that you can drag anywhere you want.
Initially, I tried with `Button` but there was a conflict with the `tap gesture` and `drag gesture`. Thus I have used Image for showing icon and added a tap gesture and drag gesture to it.

Below is the code:

```
import SwiftUI
import WebKit

struct FloatingFab : View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            WebView(request: URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://stackoverflow.com/")!))

            FloatingView()
        }
    }
}

struct WebView : UIViewRepresentable {

    let request: URLRequest

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView  {
        return WKWebView()
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
        uiView.load(request)
    }

}

struct FloatingView: View {

    @State private var currentPosition: CGSize = .zero
    @State private var newPosition: CGSize = .zero

    var body: some View {

        Image(systemName: "plus.circle.fill")
            .resizable()
            .foregroundColor(.blue)
            .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
            .offset(x: self.currentPosition.width, y: self.currentPosition.height)
            .onTapGesture(perform: {
                debugPrint("Perform you action here")
            })
            .gesture(DragGesture()
                .onChanged { value in
                    self.currentPosition = CGSize(width: value.translation.width + self.newPosition.width,
                                                  height: value.translation.height + self.newPosition.height)
            }
            .onEnded { value in
                self.currentPosition = CGSize(width: value.translation.width + self.newPosition.width,
                                              height: value.translation.height + self.newPosition.height)

                self.newPosition = self.currentPosition
                }
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: this coding is correctly, thanks you so much

Comment: pls vote if you got solution

Comment: @sambath if this answer fulfills your requirement, please select it as the accepted answer.

Comment: @user832 FloatingView is a view, How can I click the image and callback to logout of LoginView and can reload wkwebview?
because I have Login.swift one more
Login => FloatingFab.
FloatingView of image button(callback to ) => Login??????

Comment: In my code there is a line `debugPrint("perform your action here")`, replace that with your desired functionality.